# Can I add Apache cassandra nodes to DataStax (DSE) cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am in the process of migrating from Datastax (DSE) Cassandra to Apache Cassandra 3.11.

I have a cluster of 7 nodes of Datastax (DSE) Cassandra.

**Is there a way I create new cluster of apache Cassandra & connect it to DSE Cassandra so that my writes go to both DSE & Apache cassandra**

So that once my data has started to be written in both Cassandra I can migrate my Read API's gradually from DSE to Apache.

Comment: You may create a datacenter connecttiion between them to replicate data when written at both sides to both sides.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I've done this before.

First of all, find the *exact* version of the Cassandra version (not the DSE version) that your cluster is running:

```
SELECT release_version FROM system.local;

 release_version
-----------------
          3.11.4
```

You can also see this version number when connecting with `cqlsh`.  The DSE version of Cassandra will have a (long) build number added on to that.  But the idea is that the version of Apache Cassandra on new nodes should match the DSE version of Cassandra as closely as possible.

Next, build up your Apache Cassandra "replacement" nodes as *a new logical datacenter*.  Make sure that they use a different `dc_name` (than the existing nodes) in the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file.  The first node (or two) should use nodes from the existing cluster as seed nodes.  The following nodes can then use the first nodes as seeds.  Plus, the `cluster_name` needs to match.

Now check the keyspace definitions for `system_auth`, `system_traces`, `system_distributed`, and any keyspaces that the app needs.  Make sure that they're using `NetworkTopologyStrategy`.  If not, make sure it is, and configure the replication factor (RF) for the existing DC (DC name must match `dc_name` of existing DSE nodes).  Then you can extend replication to the new data center.

If current `dc_name` is `DSE_DC` and the new `dc_name` is `AC_DC`, then:

```
ALTER KEYSPACE yourkeyspace WITH replication =
   {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
    'DSE_DC': '3', 'AC_DC': '3'};
```

Once that change is done, run a nodetool rebuild on **each new Apache Cassandra node**.

```
nodetool rebuild -- DSE_DC
```

That will move the data *from* the `DSE_DC` to the current node.  Then, you should be able to switch your API by specifying the new data center name.

**Edit 20200506**

Check your data directories.  The most important thing that needs to match-up for this to work, is the SSTable format.

ver 3.11.4+

```
    43 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
    83 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Data.db
    10 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Digest.crc32
    16 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Filter.db
    17 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Index.db
  4769 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Statistics.db
    57 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-Summary.db
    92 Feb 20 08:55 md-1-big-TOC.txt
```

ver 4.0-alpha4:

```
    47 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
   107 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Data.db
    10 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Digest.crc32
    16 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Filter.db
    32 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Index.db
  4687 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Statistics.db
    66 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-Summary.db
    92 May  6 10:13 na-1-big-TOC.txt
```

You can also verify this in DataStax's [Product Compatibility Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html).

Basically, if your SSTable files are prefixed with m[a,b,c,d], then 3.11.6 should be able to work.

Comment: Thanks Aaron for the quick reply. However, currently we are using DSE 6.0.5
and when we checked :
   SELECT release_version FROM system.local;
we got 4.0.0.605
now we are migrating it to Apache 3.11.6 version, which is last stable version for apache
so we are getting error:
 MigrationManager.java:95 - Not pulling schema because release version in Gossip is not major version 3, it is 4.0.0.605
how to resolve this issue? This will be really helpful

Comment: @PuneetAgarwal Edit made.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have two questions can you plz help, badly stuck -

#1. In reference to my above question, I have DSE 6.0.5 version (SSTable bti-aa) and I was trying to add Apache Cassandra 3.11.6 into the ring but this was throwing error, so I downgraded my Apache cassandra to 3.11.3 as its sstable format is supported but when I added it into the ring it did not give any exception / error but the data is not streaming from DSE to Apache node.

#2 )  In one another DSE cluster I successfully migrated to Apache cass keeping the JVM options same as DSE, but there are intermittent spikes, plz.

Comment: @PuneetAgarwal Did you adjust replication for all keyspaces?  It won't stream data without that.  Not sure what intermittent spikes would be about.  Maybe check that `memtable_flush_writers` is set no higher than 2, and that the settings are SSD-optimized (assuming that you're using SSDs).